# Mysql reverse index and query

Tags: mysql, indexing, syntax-error, reverse

I have created a table with the following attributes

```
employee54(
    Emp_Id int, 
    First_name varchar(20),
    Middle_name varchar(20), 
    Last_name varchar(20), 
    Dept_Id int, 
    Phone_number int, 
    Address varchar(30)
)
```

I tried to make reverse index using this syntax

```
create index emp_id_list on employee54(Emp_Id) reverse;
```

and it is showing an

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'reverse'

Comment: You mean `descending`?

Comment: Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/descending-indexes.html

Comment: What's a reverse index?

Comment: Indexing is a data structure technique to efficiently retrieve the records from the database files based on some attributes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only MySQL 8.0+ supports making and using "reverse" indexes. 
Other MySQLs version only parse the ASC or DESC parts but does use them.

> A key_part specification can end with ASC or DESC to specify whether
>   index values are stored in ascending or descending order. The default
>   is ascending if no order specifier is given. ASC and DESC are not
>   permitted for HASH indexes. As of MySQL 8.0.12, ASC and DESC are not
>   permitted for SPATIAL indexes.

source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html

```
CREATE INDEX emp_id_list ON employee54(Emp_id DESC)
```

`DESC` makes a descending order index which is "reversed" index.

Comment: Thank you so much, Raymond!

Answer (score 0):

- The error message 1064 pointed directly *at* the problem (or it might have been directly *after* the problem).
- A check of the manual would show you that `ASC` and `DESC` are possible, not `reverse`.
- If you are hoping to fetch the rows in reverse order of `emp_id`, then simply do `ORDER BY emp_id DESCENDING`.  This will get you the desired results (for all versions of MySQL/MariaDB) even though pre-8.0 it does not implement index creation in reverse order.